# What is a better way to paste illustration from Illustrator to Photoshop without invisible pixels?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

For fixing gradient issues, I need to paste the Illustration from Illustrator to Photoshop. Now, the issue is explained in the image I have shown at the end.

1. This is the original illustration. For some reasons (like reuse), I can't remove the parts which are outside the artboard.
2. I need the final output in 1600x1200px . So I resized it to 1600x1200. But to maintain the illustration same *edges of illustration* (see arrows in image **1**), I simply couldn't select all and resize it. I needed to put a clipping mask on it. So I resized it perfectly with same *outlines/edges* (**1**)
3. I created a new file in Photoshop with same DPI, and 1600x1200 px resolution. Pasted the clipped illustration as Smart Object. **And here I faced the problem.** I thought it would be a perfect fit, but it didn't, **probably because of the invisible art?** And just because of that, if you know, you can't simply resize it to fit the canvas perfectly. *(NB: I could somehow fix it with resizing the pasted object in Photoshop, but I needed exact same outline/edges. I would need to do hit and trials for that. There were some imperfections of white space either in left/right/top or bottom. I don't want that.)*
4. I tried another approach to fix it. Instead of clipping mask, I cropped it. That solved all problem. Was pasted perfectly on the canvas. But that caused the problem that I have exaggerated in ( image **4**, i.e., every object gets divided and independent. As a result, the final saved image shows some imperfections. I don't want that either.)

So what can I do that to fix it or is there still any better way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Copy/paste, **Export as...** the Illustrator file to Photoshop file using artboards and open it in Photoshop.

Illustrator file:
[image: Illustrator file]

Photoshop file exported from Illustrator:

[image: Photoshop file]

Comment: Wow! That's what something I was looking for. No hit and trial. Thank you :)